# How to disable Flash in Firefox with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, browser, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

Trying to disable Flash in Firefox with Selenium in Python, using profile settings.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849116/1663942) specifies a way to do it through the GUI, but it would be better for this particular use case to do it programmatically.  Specifically, the best possible solution would allow Flash to be disabled in a newly created profile object.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable flash using the below profile.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

    def disableImages(self):
        ## Firefox profile object
        firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()

        ## Disable Flash
        firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so',
                                      'false')
        ## Set the modified profile while creating the browser object 
        self.browserHandle = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
```

Comment: Could you specify some more details like FF and selenium version ?