# Disable Shockwave Flash plugin using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In a crawling project, the Shockwave Flash plugin keeps crashing. Is there a simple way to disable it to begin with?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes: uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks, but in Chrome you cannot uninstall it, you can only disable it. However, when using selenium in the new window it is enabled again. I am looking for a command to disable it.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406719/how-to-disable-flash-in-firefox-with-selenium-in-python, it is not an exact match, it is about disable plugin using selenium and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me pretty well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = {"plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Shockwave Flash"]}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)

# Make sure to add chrome_options=options 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path,chrome_options = options)
```