# How to enable Adobe Flash in FireFox Selenium webdriver with FirefoxProfile

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-driver

I need an automated way to enable Flash in the Firefox Selenium webdriver without user interaction.

I have tried:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
//As 0 is to disable, I used 1. I don"t know what to use.
profile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 1);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

But this still requires me to click "Allow".

[This is shown all the time, even with the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARH3D.png)

Comment: No error.
Just didn't worked.
As I still had to manually click the "Allow" button.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here but, it looks to me like all you did what pass a preference to the `driver` object.  You need to tell it to _go somewhere_, also.

Comment: The site that I go into with:
driver.get(link);
Requires, Flash plugin to be allowed. And I have to press it manually.
Just want a way to automate it too.

Comment: i've edited some of the details you mentioned in the comments into the question. if i've mis-represented the problem you're facing, please update the question again.

Comment: Woodrow Barlow, I don't understand, what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

[This Post Shows how to disable Adobe flash Player in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406719/how-to-disable-flash-in-firefox-with-selenium-in-python)

And to enable it in "JAVA", Just change the false to true.

```
profile.setPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so","true");
```

And it works :)

Comment: Hi, We have still Problems with Selenium 3.5.3, geckodriver: 0.19.0 
with Firefox 55.0.3(64 Bit). 
firefoxProfile.setPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so","true");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 2);

Comment: The above post was for chrome browser and chrome driver only.

Comment: The question specifically mentions Firefox though.

Answer (score 5):

This didn't work for me:
`profile.setPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so","true");`

Instead I used: 
`profile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 2);`

I presume the "2" also activates the plugin.